# Find depth of object in iterative way

Tags: javascript, algorithm, ecmascript-6

I am writing a function for calculating the depth of an object.

Here is my recursive version which seems to work as expected:

```js
function findDepth(obj, firstCall = true) {
  if (firstCall && typeof obj !== "object") {
    return -1;
  }
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((max, k) => {
    if (typeof obj[k] === "object" && obj[k] !== null) {
      const val = findDepth(obj[k], false) + 1;
      if (val > max) {
        max = val;
      }
    }
    return max;
  }, 1);
}

const input1 = {
  a: {
    b: "test",
    c: {
      d: {
        e: {
          f: [1, 2, 3],
          g: {
            a: null,
            z: {
              d: "casdsadasdsa",
              q: {
                z: {
                  i: undefined
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      c: {
        a: "sad"
      }
    },
    d: {
      e: 5
    }
  },
  b: {
    c: {
      d: "dsada"
    }
  }
};

const input2 = {
  w: {
    d: "hello",
    f: {
      g: "dsadas",
      z: {
        b: "dsajkdasjldk",
        q: {
          w: {
            z: "dsajkdasjdla"
          }
        }
      },
      h: "dsiaodsiad"
    }
  },
  a: "test",
  b: "test2",
  c: {
    d: "hello",
    f: {
      g: "dsadas",
      z: {
        b: "dsajkdasjldk"
      },
      h: "dsiaodsiad"
    }
  },
  e: "bye"
};

console.log(findDepth(input1));
console.log(findDepth(input2));
```

Now I am trying to write an iterative version, but I cannot find the best way to make the loop work.

```js
function findDepthIterative(obj) {
  if (typeof obj !== "object") {
    return -1;
  }
  let max = 1;
  let copy = Object.assign({}, obj);
  let keys = Object.keys(copy);
  while (keys.length) {
    if (typeof copy[keys[0]] !== "object" && copy[keys[0]] !== null) {
      delete copy[keys[0]];
      keys = Object.keys(copy);
    } else {
      max++;
      copy = Object.assign({}, copy[keys[0]]);
      keys = Object.keys(copy);
    }
  }
  return max;
}

const input1 = {
  a: {
    b: "test",
    c: {
      d: {
        e: {
          f: [1, 2, 3],
          g: {
            a: null,
            z: {
              d: "casdsadasdsa",
              q: {
                z: {
                  i: undefined
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      c: {
        a: "sad"
      }
    },
    d: {
      e: 5
    }
  },
  b: {
    c: {
      d: "dsada"
    }
  }
};

const input2 = {
  w: {
    d: "hello",
    f: {
      g: "dsadas",
      z: {
        b: "dsajkdasjldk",
        q: {
          w: {
            z: "dsajkdasjdla"
          }
        }
      },
      h: "dsiaodsiad"
    }
  },
  a: "test",
  b: "test2",
  c: {
    d: "hello",
    f: {
      g: "dsadas",
      z: {
        b: "dsajkdasjldk"
      },
      h: "dsiaodsiad"
    }
  },
  e: "bye"
};

console.log(findDepthIterative(input1));
console.log(findDepthIterative(input2));
```

As you can see from the output and the code, it just takes the first property inside the loop:

```
while (keys.length) {
    if (typeof copy[keys[0]] !== "object" && copy[keys[0]] !== null) {
      delete copy[keys[0]];
      keys = Object.keys(copy);
    } else {
      max++;
      copy = Object.assign({}, copy[keys[0]]);
      keys = Object.keys(copy);
    }
  }
```

The idea was to delete the property each iteration, but I am not getting in the right way. 
I tried to change it with `copy[keys[keys.length - 1]]` but in this way it takes only the last property instead. 
Actually the issue is how to loop over all the keys, on all the depth levels, as in the recursive version.

Any suggestion about how to implement this algorithm in an iterative way?

Even any suggestion on how to improve the recursive one (or if I am missing something) is more than welcome.

**p.s. NO LOADASH, UNDERSCORE, RAMDA, or whatever. Just Vanilla JS**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to iterate could be a depth first search using a stack.

```js
function f(obj){
  let stack = Object.keys(obj).map(k => [obj[k], 1]);
  let max = 0;

  while (stack.length){
    let [maybeObj, d] = stack.pop();
    max = Math.max(max, d);
    if (typeof maybeObj == 'object' && maybeObj !== null)
      Object.keys(maybeObj).map(k =>
        stack.push([maybeObj[k], d + 1]));
  }

  return max;
}
```

We could also make the recursion slightly more succinct:

```js
function f(obj){
  if (typeof obj !== 'object' || obj === null)
    return 0;

  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, k) => 
    Math.max(acc, 1 + f(obj[k])), 0);
}
```

Comment: Heh, or as Mark Meyer suggested, use Object.values.

Comment: your `k` is undefined inside the while, it just exists inside the first `map` function

Comment: @quirimmo this answer does not seem to be appreciated, typos notwithstanding.

Comment: For now, you'll have to live with my mistake. (This answer has the same algorithm as Mark Meyer's. Go figure.)

Comment: brilliant thanks a million, and thanks also for the syntactic sugar of the recursive version :) Great!

Answer (score 5):

You just need to keep a stack and push children into it while keeping track of the current depth. You can keep track of that by pushing an array of `[depth, obj]` into the stack and then when you `pop()` add one to the depth before pushing children.

```js
const input1  = {w: {d: "hello",f: {g: "dsadas",z: {b: "dsajkdasjldk",q: {w: {z: "dsajkdasjdla"}}},h: "dsiaodsiad"}},a: "test",b: "test2",c: {d: "hello",f: {g: "dsadas",z: {b: "dsajkdasjldk"},h: "dsiaodsiad"}},e: "bye"};
  
  
function findDepthIterative(obj) {
    if (typeof obj !== "object") {
      return -1;
    }
    let max = 0;
    // current depth, children
    let stack = [[0, Object.values(obj)]];
    
    while(stack.length){
        let [depth, cur] = stack.pop()
        if (depth > max) max = depth

        if (typeof cur === "object" && cur !== null){
            Object.values(cur).forEach(c => stack.push([depth+1, c]))     
        }
    }
    return max
  }
  

console.log(findDepthIterative(input1))

// sanity check:
const depth0 = {}
const depth1 = {a:1}
const depth2 = {a:{b:2}}

console.log(findDepthIterative(depth0))
console.log(findDepthIterative(depth1))
console.log(findDepthIterative(depth2))
```

Comment: sorry my bad I deleted the comment, there was a typeof, even the not strict equal was fine :) sorry again

Comment: That's okay `===` is better.

Comment: @quirimmo brilliant? I posted the exact same algorithm a minute before. No disrespect to your eloquent answer, Mark Meyer. +1 from me.

Comment: @גלעדברקן why are you taking it so badly? I am going through your solution too just give me the time to do it

Comment: @quirimmo I must've had a bad day, ha ha. Sorry about that.

Comment: @גלעדברקן MarkMeyer guys your solutions are actually the same, and they are both great. I did upvote both, but I can mark just one as correct (I guess). 
Mark do you mind if I choose his one? He has less points than you, and he also took less upvotes :)

Comment: It's always up to the OP, @quirimmo — and they came in a minute quicker!

Comment: thanks to both of you guys... Mark he had a bad day, so let's try to make him happier :D thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You should use an array instead of the object which won't work properly if there are duplicate keys. The array should contain all the objects that occur at a certain level. For each iteration, you map the array into a new one containing the previous objects' direct children:

```
function findDepthIterative(obj) {
  if (typeof obj !== "object") {
    return -1;
  }

  let arr = [obj];                                          // the array containing the objects that occur at a certain level, initially contains obj being the only object at the first level
  let levels = 0;                                           // levels counter

  do {                                                      // keep doing this
    levels++;                                               // increment the levels counter

    let newArr = [];                                        // make a new array for the next level
    arr.forEach(obj => {                                    // populate it with the old level objects' children
      for(let key in obj) {
        if(obj[key] && typeof obj[key] === "object") {
          newArr.push(obj[key]);
        }
      }
    });
    arr = newArr;                                          // make arr the new array of object (next level)
  } while (arr.length);                                    // while there are still levels with objects in them

  return levels;
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
function findDepthIterative(obj) {
  if (typeof obj !== "object") {
    return -1;
  }

  let arr = [obj];
  let levels = 0;

  do {
    levels++;
    
    let newArr = [];
    arr.forEach(obj => {
      for(let key in obj) {
        if(obj[key] && typeof obj[key] === "object") {
          newArr.push(obj[key]);
        }
      }
    });
    arr = newArr;
  } while (arr.length);

  return levels;
}

const input1 = {
  a: {
    b: "test",
    c: {
      d: {
        e: {
          f: [1, 2, 3],
          g: {
            a: null,
            z: {
              d: "casdsadasdsa",
              q: {
                z: {
                  i: undefined
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      c: {
        a: "sad"
      }
    },
    d: {
      e: 5
    }
  },
  b: {
    c: {
      d: "dsada"
    }
  }
};

const input2 = {
  w: {
    d: "hello",
    f: {
      g: "dsadas",
      z: {
        b: "dsajkdasjldk",
        q: {
          w: {
            z: "dsajkdasjdla"
          }
        }
      },
      h: "dsiaodsiad"
    }
  },
  a: "test",
  b: "test2",
  c: {
    d: "hello",
    f: {
      g: "dsadas",
      z: {
        b: "dsajkdasjldk"
      },
      h: "dsiaodsiad"
    }
  },
  e: "bye"
};

console.log(findDepthIterative(input1));
console.log(findDepthIterative(input2));
```

Comment: thanks a lot! makes absolutely sense. Maybe I just prefer the solution with the stack, even if the logic is pretty the same. Thanks again :)